# How can I transfer from using IEEEconf in Overleaf to ShareLaTeX?

Tags: overleaf

I have finished writing a project in Overleaf, and have now been asked to share it using ShareLatex, which I've never used before.

I created a ShareLatex account and copy and pasted my entire Overleaf text into the ShareLatex editor. I was using an ieeeconf template in Overleaf.

It starts like this:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}   
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              
\overrideIEEEmargins
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[a4paper,portrait,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lscape}
```

The error is as follows:

```
LaTeX Error: File `ieeeconf.cls' not found.
The compiler cannot find the file you want to include. 
Make sure that you have uploaded the file and specified the file location correctly.
```

My issue is that I'm unaware of any files because Overleaf doesn't require you to upload any files. It obviously uses some ieeeconf.cls file, but I'm unsure of where this is or how to get hold of it to upload to ShareLatex.

Can someone help me in solving this issue please?

**Solution**

When on an Overleaf project, by clicking on the 'Project' tab on the task bar, you can see all of the files pertinent to the LaTex project. At the bottom of these is a 'Download as zip' option. Once you have downloaded all of the files as a zip, you can go to ShareLatex and select 'Upload' on the top left of your project area. Simply select all of the files from the zip folder on your computer and the entire project from Overleaf will be replicated in ShareLatex.

Comment: You should be able to, in overleaf, download the whole project as a zip file. I think that should have the file you are looking for (I'm not that good with overleaf either, so i'm not sure)

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen That solves the issue completely. If you would like to post it as an answer then I will accept it.

Comment: they are now the same company. Whoever is asking you about that probably doesn't really know the whole story.

Comment: @ODP I have now added the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Updated to a better manual:

When you open one of the templates that use the ieeeconf documentclass in overleaf the project has the `ieeeconf.cls` file already. To download it click the project button button:
[image]

This wil open a menu to the left with all the files in the directory:
[image]

Here you can select download as zip to get all the files in the project.
Or you can simply copy the contents of `ieeeconf.cls` to a file with the same name in your ShareLaTeX project.

#### Quick note:

Last summer Overleaf bought ShareLaTeX, and they are currently merging. The last thing I read was that the merge would be complete in either April or May of 2018. Their reasoning was that ShareLaTeX has the better collaboration editor, while overleaf is better at doing ''What you see is what you get'' So sometime in the future there might be a simple `migrate` button, or it might be okay for you just to send the people you share with to your overleaf link ;-)

## Original answer:

You can download the project as a zip file from overleaf, this download includes all extra files you might need.

You can then bring these files into sharelatex ;-)